# What is a shorter way of comparing Boolean objects in Java 6?

Tags: java, boolean, compare

I’m using Java 6.  I have two Boolean objects, a and b.  How do I compare the two in terms of their value?  I have come up with this, but it seems really long and messy …

```
(a == null && b == null) || (a != null && b != null && a.booleanValue().equals(b.booleanValue()))
```

I like Apache’s StringUtils.equals(a, b) method for comparing strings, but there doesn’t seem to be an equivalent method for BooleanUtils.

Comment: You don't really need to extract primitive value out from a wrapper Object if you want just to compare objects. Each wrapper class in java has overridden `equals` method, which is smart enough to compare objects of the same type. Moreover `a.booleanValue().equals()` will give you a compile error, since return type of `Boolean.booleanValue()` is primitive type `boolean` and it doesn't have any methods.  Peter in his answer is comparing 2 objects directly  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492014/what-is-a-shorter-way-of-comparing-boolean-objects-in-java-6#40492101

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following for any two Objects including two `Boolean`

```
a == null ? b == null : a.equals(b);
```

This works for Java 1.0+

Comment: @utaco a.equals (null) should always return false. Or at least it does for Boolean.

Comment: you are right. i also realised boolean after post my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the compareTo in the class boolean.. it is avaliable since 1.5

take a look to this snippet

```
private static int compare(Boolean a, Boolean b) {
    // if (a == null || b == null) {
    // return -1;
    // }else {
    // return a.compareTo(b);
    // }

    return (a == null || b == null) ? -1 : a.compareTo(b);
}
```

the return line is doing the same as the commented one...